# Как создать виртуальную веб-камеру и отправить в неё свои изображения

Tags: swift, macos, потоки-данных

Я пишу программу для OS X на Swift. Моя программа уже делает следующее: берёт кадры с реальной веб камеры, обрабатывает их (затирает лица на каждом кадре), затем выводит получившиеся кадры во вьюхе. Получается такое же видео как с реальной вебкамеры, но без лиц.

Я хочу создать виртуальную веб-камеру и сделать так, чтобы если человек в скайпе или любой другой программе выбрал, в качестве видео источника не обычную веб-камеру, а мою виртуальную, он видел те самые кадры, которые я уже обработал.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как создать виртуальную камеру и отправить на неё свои изображения.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что необходимо твою виртуальную камеру объсяыить как "устройство", что бы она была доступна в любой другой программе?

Comment: Да, абсолютно верно.

Comment: Хм, надо полагать, что это очень и очень сложно. Так как тебе надо "перехватить" в самой системе вызов камеры. А Эпл это не любит и не позволяет. Надо подумать.

Comment: Есть программа [CamWiz](http://www.camwizapp.com/) Она создаёт виртуальную камеру и отправляет туда свой видеопоток. Судя по интерфейсу и не самому полезному функционалу, я думаю что это всё же немного проще, чем «очень и очень сложно». Тем более программа ставится через апстор, а значит эплы ничего против не имеют. Но я уже весь интернет перерыл и ничего не могу найти на эту тему, так что видимо это действительно не просто.